# Cant integrate Static Library in Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

We are trying to integrate a static library in to a cocoa touch framework to create a universal framework. I have compiled the framework for 86_64, i386, armv7 and arm64, but when we are uploading the file to apple store, i386 and x86_64 exhibit problems.

The error is :

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Unsupported architectures. Your executable contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]

We have tried stripping the unsupported libraries via :

http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

Then it returns:

"No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable."

I would much appreciate help on this matter

Comment: Please post the exact commands and the exact errors.

Comment: Hello again sir,

itunes connect returns such an error:

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Unsupported architectures. Your executable contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'"